# How to configure Nginx for Vanilla Forums 2.3?

Tags: nginx, vanilla-forums

Since Vanilla Forums 2.3, the old rewrite solutions doesn’t work anymore.
Do you know what’s the cleanest new solution?
Here is some info from the docs: http://docs.vanillaforums.com/developer/backend/

Thank you.